MySQL Copy Column From Table to other Table
i have 3 tables:
ec2

id_resource
name_resource
rds

id_resource
name_resource
events

id_event
id_resource
¿name_resource?
I want that in the table events if the field id_resource match with the id_resource field of the other two tables it copy the information of the name_resource in the table events.
How is the more consistent and efficient form of do this?
Thanks!

Copying data like this is generally a bad idea. Use joins to fetch the data from the other table as needed, rather than entering it redundantly in both tables.


[edited]

@Orion if both are tables in the same mysql then you can try
UPDATE events JOIN ec2 ON events.id_resource = ec2.id_resource SET
events.name_resource = ec2.name_resource;


UPDATE events JOIN rds ON events.id_resource = rds.id_resource SET
events.name_resource = rds.name_resource; for trigger CREATE TRIGGER
update_name_resource_from_ec2 AFTER INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   UPDATE events   SET name_resource = (     SELECT
ec2.name_resource     FROM ec2     WHERE ec2.id_resource =
NEW.id_resource   )   WHERE id_event = NEW.id_event; END

and CREATE TRIGGER update_name_resource_from_rds AFTER INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW BEGIN   UPDATE events   SET name_resource = (     SELECT rds.name_resource     FROM rds     WHERE rds.id_resource = NEW.id_resource   )   WHERE id_event = NEW.id_event; END

And how can I do so that every time there are new inserts in the events table it does this automatic update? @logendher

@Orion then you better set up replication between the two mysql instances. DBA sister site of SO can provide tou with help if you get stuck with replication.

EC2 and RDS represent two different mysql instances. You can't simply cross update between them via sql.

This doesn't look like valid MySQL syntax to me. In MySQL you use JOIN. I think you're using SQL-Server syntax.

@Shadow Where does the question say anything about different database instances?

@Orion You can use a trigger to perform the update whenever the table is modified.

@Orion Use Trigger to make a new Inserts in the events table
CREATE TRIGGER update_name_resource_from_ec2 AFTER INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW BEGIN   UPDATE events   SET name_resource = (     SELECT ec2.name_resource     FROM ec2     WHERE ec2.id_resource = NEW.id_resource   )   WHERE id_event = NEW.id_event; END
try this

@Shadow I do understand EC2 and RDS represent two different mysql Instances. but there is the chance by using the replication and application logic which he can implement to do this... unless we dont have much information we cant provide actual solution, i shared my knowledge what i know

There isn't two different mysql instances. Are only different tables inside a same mysql instance.

@Orion then why is the question tagged with EC2 and RDS tags?

@Orion if both are tables in the same mysql then you can try
UPDATE events JOIN ec2 ON events.id_resource = ec2.id_resource SET events.name_resource = ec2.name_resource;
UPDATE events JOIN rds ON events.id_resource = rds.id_resource SET events.name_resource = rds.name_resource;
for trigger
CREATE TRIGGER update_name_resource_from_ec2 AFTER INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW BEGIN   UPDATE events   SET name_resource = (     SELECT ec2.name_resource     FROM ec2     WHERE ec2.id_resource = NEW.id_resource   )   WHERE id_event = NEW.id_event; END

and
CREATE TRIGGER update_name_resource_from_rds AFTER INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW BEGIN   UPDATE events   SET name_resource = (     SELECT rds.name_resource     FROM rds     WHERE rds.id_resource = NEW.id_resource   )   WHERE id_event = NEW.id_event; END
